# Using Svelte, how can I escape curly braces in the HTML?

Tags: svelte

I want to be able to show a code example in my Svelte component, but the example has curly braces, i.e

```
<script>
//no JS needed
</script>

<p>Here's a sample function</p>
<pre><code>
  function test(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
</code></pre>
```

Notice how the function has curly braces? That seems to be confusing the Svelte compiler. Is there a way to escape those other than this?

```
<script>
//no JS needed
</script>

<p>Here's a sample function</p>
<pre><code>
  function test(e) {'{'}
    console.log(e)
  {'}'}
</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I know of 3 ways to escape curly braces in Svelte:

1. Using `{'{'}` and `{'}'}` (What you're already doing)
2. Using `&#123;` and `&#125;`

   or `&lbrace;` and `&rbrace;`

   or `&lcub;` and `&rcub;`
3. Using template literals

   You could wrap your whole code inside a template literal.

[Examples on svelte.dev's REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2290fc67e7c0479881a266abb34e0f4d?version=3.20.1)
(Partly because I'm having a hard time escaping characters here on SO...)

---

Discussions on the subject on GitHub:

https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2924

https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/1318

---

My example on svelte.dev's REPL copy/pasted here just in case something happens to it...

```svelte
<h3>Escaping every curly brace</h3>
<pre><code>
  function test(e) {'{'}
    console.log(e)
  {'}'}
</code></pre>


<h3>Wrapping the whole code block in a string literal</h3>
<pre><code>
  {`
  function test(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
  `}
</code></pre>


<h3>Using &#123; and &#125;</h3>
<pre><code>
  function test(e) &#123;
    console.log(e)
  &#125;
</code></pre>
```