# How do I prevent Svelte from flattening JSON inside a <pre> tag?

Tags: json, svelte, pre

As demonstrated in [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/9dfd496dc742454c8abe0dbef6120e51?version=3.42.6), inserting JSON between `<pre>` tags results in an error. My question was *going* to be, "What's up with this error?", but then I realized that the single brackets are seen as executable code by Svelte (duh), so I can't just treat it like HTML.

THAT SAID…

How can I take this content, which works fine as raw HTML…

```
<pre>
{
  "num": 2,
    "obj": { "foo": "bar" }
}
</pre>
```

and keep the carriage returns so that it renders with white space, like so ↓ ?

```
{
  "num": 2,
    "obj": { "foo": "bar" }
}
```

---

Note: My [first attempt](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.42.6) gets past the error, but wipes out all white space before the `pre` tag can protect it:

```
{"num":2,"obj":{"foo":"bar"}}
```

Hopefully I'm missing something bone-headedly simple here.

Comment: `<pre>{JSON.stringify({ "num": 2, "obj": { "foo": "bar" }}, null, 2)}</pre>`, or assign it to a variable in the `<script>` section as a template literal. [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/544fc358e1cb4f25a5f8bb45079a65b3?version=3.42.6)

Comment: Argh! I find it so difficult to remember to include `null, 2`. Thanks for the reminder, @pilchard!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the three options that come to mind.

A straight [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) inside a code block.

```
<pre>{`{
  num: 2,
  obj: { "foo": "bar" }
}`}
</pre>
```

A template literal declared in the script section

```
<script>
    let json = `{
  num: 2,
  obj: { "foo": "bar" }
}`
</script>

<pre>{json}</pre>
```

JSON.stringify()

```
<pre>{JSON.stringify({ "num": 2, "obj": { "foo": "bar" }}, null, 2)}</pre>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/544fc358e1cb4f25a5f8bb45079a65b3?version=3.42.6)

Also see: [Using Svelte, how can I escape curly braces in the HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61089042/using-svelte-how-can-i-escape-curly-braces-in-the-html)