# Input regex pattern with curly braces in Svelte

Tags: html, regex, svelte

In my svelte file I have a form with input and regex validation pattern:

```html
<form action="/action">
  <label for="country_code">Country code:</label>
  <input type="text" id="country_code" name="country_code"
  pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" title="Three letter country code"><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But Svelte treats curly braces `{` `}`as special characters. So this part of the pattern `{3}` breaks the pattern in Svelte. In my case the form has to be fully accessible and so has to work without JavaScript so no  possible :-( It took me whole yesterday without any luck how to solve this. Either I break regex or svelte syntax.

Thank everyone for suggestions and help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61089042/using-svelte-how-can-i-escape-curly-braces-in-the-html

Comment: @Nick: If you find a duplicate, please also cast a close vote.

Comment: @H.B. I know nothing about svelte, so was not confident that it was a dupe. But it seemed like it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/action">
  <label for="country_code">Country code:</label>
  <input type="text" id="country_code" name="country_code"
  pattern="[A-Za-z]{'{'}3{'}'}" title="Three letter country code"><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Or even simlier `pattern="[A-Za-z]{'{'}3}"`, in case that first curly brace is escaped, second curly brase ignored, and it is not special svelt symbol.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought I had it right like this but probably some typo was there So this is really duplicate as it is just a common svelte curly braces escaping, regex means noting special.

Comment: pattern={'[A-Za-z]{3}'} (setting attribute as string) seems much pleasing to my eyes.